# Differentiating between video and image upload in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I can upload either of image or video from my file. I've set the configuration file for image as follows :

```
        $config['upload_path'] = './docs/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '200';
        $config['max_width']  = '250';
        $config['max_height']  = '250';
        $config['file_name']  = md5(rand().time());

        $this -> load -> library('upload', $config);
```

But when I'll upload video, this configuration will not work as I need to be able to upload much bigger size file ( video ). Is there any way after submitting to find out what I've uploaded ( img/video ) and based on that I can enable the configuration file.

The configuration for video is as follows :

```
            $configVideo['upload_path'] = './docs/';
            $configVideo['max_size'] = '50240';
            $configVideo['allowed_types'] = 'avi|flv|wmv|mp3|wma';
            $configVideo['overwrite'] = FALSE;
            $configVideo['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
            $video_name = $date.$_FILES['video']['name'];
            $configVideo['file_name'] = $video_name;

            $this->load->library('upload', $configVideo);
            $this->upload->initialize($configVideo);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **$_FILES** to find out the type first.
*untested*

```
$type = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
switch ($type) {
   case 'gif':
   case 'jpg':
   case 'png':
      // do img config setup
      break;
   case 'avi':
   case 'flv':
   case 'wmv':
   case 'mp3':
   case 'wma':
      // do video config
      break;
}
```

Or if you use different names for the files in the form then why not try;

[**updated**]

```
$config['upload_path'] = './docs/';
if (is_array($_FILES) && isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
    // is an image
    $config['upload_path'] = './docs/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '200';
    $config['max_width']  = '250';
    $config['max_height']  = '250';
    $config['file_name']  = md5(rand().time());
} elseif (is_array($_FILES) && isset($_FILES['video']['name'])) {
    // is a video
    $config['max_size'] = '50240';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'avi|flv|wmv|mp3|wma';
    $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
    $video_name = $date.$_FILES['video']['name'];
    $config['file_name'] = $video_name;
}

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I am still stuck in the problem In view video file name is video and image file name is image. how do I get it in controller and then set the configuration. I am still learning. Please help me out. Thanks once again for the response.

Comment: I have added some extra bits to the second code example (see updated). $this will run the upload library with the correct settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot once again. When I try to display using echo $config['file_name'] ; it throws an error : Message: Undefined index: file_name. What can be the possible error?

Comment: Where are you trying to echo the file name?

Comment: I am trying to echo it in controller itself. Just after loading the library, and I've commented the load-> view line so that I can see the output. :(

Comment: $data = array('name' => 'video', 'id' => 'video');  echo form_upload($data); $data = array('name' => 'image', 'id' => 'image', 'file' => 'jpg'); echo form_upload($data); This is what I am submitting from the view. I can submit either of these two.

Comment: Rather then fill up this with comments goto http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12424/room-for-rooneyl-and-shashi-roy